# Is the measurement of distance and position of far away objects accurate?

Tags: gravity, space-telescope, exoplanet

Considering that light is affected by gravity, how accurate are our measurements of distant stars and galaxies?
When light passes through objects with great mass, such as Jupiter size planets, or black holes, shouldn't it change its course and result in a deviation of trajectory?
Does the light we see with telescopes when observing the many celestial bodies in the sky pinpoint the real location of such bodies in the past, or was its past location divergent from the point in space indicated by the light reaching us?